# insertion in nested serializer in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

Currently i am using django rest_framework.I have two different class name as Customer and Customerinfo . My code is working properely . Now I want to insert value in the customer serializer. In CustomerSerializer it has Customerinfo field. 
These are the serializer:

```
    class CustomerinfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Choice
            fields = ['id','phone']


    class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        info = CustomerinfoSerializer(many=True, source='customerinfo_set')

        class Meta:
            model = Question
            fields = ["id","name","info"]
```

How can i use post method to insert value ? sample values are:

```
{
        "name": "user10",
        "info":

            [

               { "phone":12345
               },

               { "phone":54321
               }
            ]

    }
```

Comment: Can you add your models?

Comment: if you're asking how to make a test and populate your database you can use requests package. simple example: request.post(url, data) - data being a dictionary as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly your looking for [writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

As documentation says,

> by default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support
>   write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create
>   create() method.

You could try something similar to this (but you need to adjust your naming):

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    info = CustomerinfoSerializer(many=True, source='customerinfo_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ["id", "name", "info"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        info_data = validated_data.pop('info')
        question = Question.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for info in info_data:
            Choice.objects.create(question=question, **info)
        return question
```

Comment: In this line  `info_data = validated_data.pop('info')`

It shows **KeyError: 'info'**